# How to sort a column of a DataGridView in VB.net (String)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have been trying to sort a column in DataGridView (vb.net) and as far as it is considered as string, can not be sorted properly. 
it shows something like this : 
1
1
1
10
2
2
26
3
...

any suggestion ?

Comment: Why are saying that strings cannot be sorted? Can you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: No , I meant, one of columns is numeric and I want to be sorted, but it considered as string
for Ex. it must show : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 

but it shows : 1 10 11 12 ...

my question is how can I convert this column to Integer , so it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default type of `DataGridView Cells` is `String`. But if you set a different type in the `DataSource`, the corresponding cells would behave accordingly. Sample code:

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(Integer))
dt.Rows.Add(1)
dt.Rows.Add(10)
dt.Rows.Add(2)

DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

If you sort the first column of `DataGridView1`, it would show a numerical behaviour (e.g., `1, 2, 10` or `10, 2, 1`).

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the datatype of the column to integer. because string is the default datatype  for the columns. you can change the data type with following code:

datatable1.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(Integer))